# Block mobile.twitter.com using etc/hosts

Tags: windows, windows-10, blocking, hosts

I'd like to block the webpage mobile.twitter.com using etc/hosts. Using this code, I can block many websites including twitter.com, but **mobile.twitter.com works normally**

```
127.0.0.1 www.twitter.com
127.0.0.1 twitter.com
127.0.0.1 www.mobile.twitter.com
127.0.0.1 mobile.twitter.com
```

*Windows 10

Comment: Flush your browser cache and reboot your device to flush your DNS cache.

Comment: I agree with davidgo. There's nothing wrong with the host file you changed. After we changed the host file you need to open CMD window and type "ipconfig /flushdns" to clear dns cache. Then you would can't access this website. Note: This trick might not work for websites that are served via HTTPs and IPv6 protocol, so you need to map Facebook to IPv6’s localhost notation as well.

Comment: thankyou @davidgo for the help otherwise it would have taken me forever to figure that out

Answer (score 2):

As @davidgo pointed out in the comments, you just need to clear all the cache data from your browser (if it's Chrome,
just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>) but your host file is alright.

After clearing cache, open Command Prompt and flush your DNS with the following command: `ipconfig/flushdns`. 
This should work.